# group outputs by extension and chain one of these for next process

Tags: nextflow

One of my nextflow processes *SORT_BAM* creates three types of files:

1. *sorted.bam
2. *sorted.bam.bai
3. *flagstat.txt

I want to use **sorted.bam** files as an input for the last process *ADD_RG*, which must not commence prior to *sorted.bam file(s) generation.

I have tried reading channel operator but can't figure out how to implement it. Probably something along the lines of grouping *sorted.bam and chaining to next process? or emit *sorted.bam as xyz and then chain xyz to ADD_RG process?

I have the contents of two modules and nextflow file below.

```
#module SORT_BAM
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

process SORT_BAM {
  debug true

  publishDir 'results/bams/sorted', mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

  input:
  path bam

  output:
  path "*"

  
  // make sure you are using recent version of samtools to avoid issues with -o option
 
  script:
  """
  samtools sort $bam -o ${bam}_sorted.bam
  samtools index ${bam}_sorted.bam
  samtools flagstat ${bam}_sorted.bam -O tsv >> ${bam}_flagstat.txt
  """
}


#module ADD_RG
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow

process ADD_RG {
  debug true

  publishDir 'results/bams/RG_bams', mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

  input:
  path bam

  output:
  path "*sortedRG.bam", emit: RG_bam_files

shell:
    '''
    SUFFIX=$(echo !{bam} | cut -d"_" -f 2)
    
    picard AddOrReplaceReadGroups \
      I=!{bam} \
      O=!{bam}_sortedRG.bam \
      RGID=$(echo !{bam.baseName} | cut -d"_" -f 3-5) \
      RGLB="lib1"\
      RGPL="illumina" \
      RGPU="safi_${SUFFIX}" \
      RGSM="safi_${SUFFIX}"
    '''
}


#nextflow file
#!/usr/bin/env nextflow
nextflow.enable.dsl=2


params.genome_index = file("$baseDir/genome/fEpiCoi_cnag1_curated_primary.no_mt.fa")

// These paths are relative to the workflow .nf file
include { TRIM } from './modules/trim.nf'
include { BWA } from './modules/bwa.nf'
include { SAM_TO_BAM } from './modules/sam2bam.nf'
include { SORT_BAM } from './modules/sort_bam.nf'
include { ADD_RG } from './modules/add_RG.nf'

Channel
  .fromFilePairs("$baseDir/subset_fq/*_{1,2}.fq.gz", checkIfExists:true)
  .set{ paired_reads }

workflow {

    genome = params.genome_index
    TRIM(paired_reads)
    BWA(TRIM.out.trimmed_seqs, genome)
    SAM_TO_BAM(BWA.out.sam_files)
    SORT_BAM(SAM_TO_BAM.out.bam_files)
    ADD_RG(????????)  
}
```

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `output: path "*"` in the `SORT_BAM` process will cause each file emitted to be individually sent to the next process. That includes the `${bam}_flagstat.txt`, which would cause the the process to throw an error.

If you are more careful about your output declaration you could solve this. Something like this:

```
process SORT_BAM {
  debug true

  publishDir 'results/bams/sorted', mode: 'copy', overwrite: false

  input:
  path bam

  output:
  tuple path("${bam}_sorted.bam"), path("${bam}_sorted.bam.bai"), emit: sorted_bams
  path("${bam}_flagstat.txt"), emit: bam_flagstat 

  script:
  """
  samtools sort $bam -o ${bam}_sorted.bam
  samtools index ${bam}_sorted.bam
  samtools flagstat ${bam}_sorted.bam -O tsv >> ${bam}_flagstat.txt
  """
}
```

Notice that I've moved the flagstat away from the sorted bam channel as I don't think it's needed for RG assignment, but easay to change.

Here is the input declaration for the `ADD_RG`:

```
  input:
  tuple path(bam), path(bai)
```

Then the workflow declaration would become:

```
workflow {
    genome = params.genome_index
    TRIM(paired_reads)
    BWA(TRIM.out.trimmed_seqs, genome)
    SAM_TO_BAM(BWA.out.sam_files)
    SORT_BAM(SAM_TO_BAM.out.bam_files)
    ADD_RG(SORT_BAM.out.sorted_bams)  
}
```

Comment: I have incorporated the code from above, works (partly) fine but only generates two of the four expected outputs for ADD_RG process.

`executor >  local (20)
[71/c18fd1] process > SORT_BAM (4)                   [100%] 4 of 4 ✔
[de/030a68] process > ADD_RG (4)                     [ 50%] 2 of 4`

Comment: It says `2 of 4` in the `ADD_RG` process. Are the remaining 2 still running? That's what it looks like to me.

Comment: It runs a bit erratic for me, probably something to do with the university cluster I run it on, randomly gives me 0-4 output files when I run it.